# Android App Settings Menu, Can't get it to work

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I've gone through a half dozen tutorials at least now and can't get a simple settings menu to work for my app.

**What Works**

- Settings in activity menu
- Settings activity opens (preference activity)
- Settings fragment for "Dark Background" shows up, with checkbox
- I can click and unclick the checkbox and it is remembered

** What doesn't work**

- I cannot get the checkbox to change a value in my Main Activity
- I cannot have the value change as soon as it is clicked and update my layout based on the value

Basically, I have a settings menu with one option. "Dark Background?" That is either true or false. I want that once it is set to true (checked) the background of my main activity (and settings activity) both change to a different color (doesn't matter what color for now).

Here is my code, please also note the comments...

*SettingsActivity.java*

```
...
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity  implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener{

    public static final String KEY_BACKGROUND_COLOR = "background_checkbox";
    private CheckBoxPreference mCheckBoxPreference;
    public boolean mBgPref = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        mCheckBoxPreference = (CheckBoxPreference) getPreferenceScreen()
                .findPreference(KEY_BACKGROUND_COLOR);


        // Display the fragment as the main content.
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Load the preferences from an XML resource
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);
        }

    }

    // findPreference is deprecated... What should go here instead?
    // persistBoolean gives me an error (persistBoolean(boolean) is undefined for the type SettingsActivity)
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
            String key) {
        Preference mCheckBoxPref = findPreference(KEY_BACKGROUND_COLOR);
        if (mCheckBoxPref.isEnabled()) {
            persistBoolean(mBgPref);
        }
    }
}
```

*MainActivity.java*

```
...

    // Preference change listener
    private PreferenceChangeListener mPreferenceListener = null;
    SharedPreferences prefs;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ...
        mBackground = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.background);
    ...
        // Manage prefs
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        mPreferenceListener = new PreferenceChangeListener(); // Cannot instantiate the type PreferenceChangeListener
        prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(mPreferenceListener); //The method registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener) in the type SharedPreferences is not applicable for the arguments (PreferenceChangeListener)
...
```

*pref_general.xml

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="background_checkbox"
        android:summary="@string/backgroundColorSummary"
        android:title="@string/backgroundColor" />


</PreferenceScreen>
```

**Summary:** I can't find any good resources to help me do this and it seems that the preferences interface has changed a lot recently and a lot of the code has been deprecated and changed. How can I get this simple task to work (change my background color when checkbox is selected)?

Answer (score 0):

I recently found the same thing, I did some research and I think its to do with this bug:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6052

I think whats happened is between android versions they have removed this method:

And now expect you to do this:

```
listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
      public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {

    //Stuff here. 

      }
    };


}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
    super.onPause();
}
```